# How do I acquire Armour boxes?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I noticed on the Trading Post that there is a category called 'Containers' which lists armour boxes, which looking at the description contain a full set of armour.

Does anyone know how these are acquired? There seems to be some talk around using the Mystic Forge to create them.

Can someone tell me the recipe for crafting these using the Mystic Forge?

Comment: I give it about 4 hours before someone edits this question to change it to American spelling. FREEDOM.

Comment: I've played DCSS too much. The American spelling looks weird to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.gw2db.com/items/containers

They are created by the crafting professions armorsmiths make the boxes. You don't actually need the Mystic Forge to create them. But you do need the Mystic Forge to create the recipe for the box.

Info can be found here:
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge#Armor_Box_.2F_Satchel_Recipes

> Recipes for full armor sets can be created from the crafted chest piece. They will allow you to craft armor boxes, which contain every piece of an armor set. The following formula does NOT give you the full armor set, only the recipe to make it. Also note that armor acquired by karma and random world drop, cannot be used to make a recipe.

Comment: So I take it that it's just a shortcut way of creating a whole set?

Comment: @DavidYell It is, but don't do it just yet because it costs more to make the whole set once then item per item.

Comment: @Lyrion Which is pretty... stupid of Anet IMO.

Comment: @TerryChia True, but they are going to put a fix up for it.

Comment: @TerryChia: actually, it's not stupid at all, it's quite intentional. It's mainly for people with high-level crafters with sufficient materials who want to take a shortcut and create a whole set in one go rather than piece by piece, e.g. for their alts or for guildmates etc. Think about it. Making such a shortcut _cheaper_ rather than more expensive - now that would be stupid.

Comment: @aaamos That is just plain silly,even if you have sufficient materials why would you not just craft them part by part? It would be cheaper...

Comment: @Lyrion: If you're high enough level, you'll have enough money and materials gathered up that you won't care about the difference - but you'll appreciate the time and inventory space you've saved by paying slightly more. Or, if you're not one of the super rich ;-) you can take advantage of the fact that there are such people who'll happily pay high amounts to quickly get a decent set of armour for their alt. Just take a peek at [GW2 Spidy](http://www.gw2spidy.com/crafting/4) to see what I mean - it can be quite lucrative.

Comment: @aaamos I would like to see people complain in RL when buying in bulk is more expensive then buying it one by one...

Comment: @Lyrion: Agreed... though people tend to find reasons to complain about... well, about pretty much everything ;-) If you need an analogy to better understand it, think about cooking - buying the ingredients and cooking something yourself is cheaper than buying a pre-made meal, but takes more time, more effort, and more space in your fridge.

Comment: @aaamos I'm going to say 1 more thing then leave it be :p. But according to your analogy, this would mean that if you want to cook for 4 people it is cheaper to make dinner seperate for 1 person at a time then buying it all and cooking for 4 persons... it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lyrion: I do see your point, but don't look at it like buying in bulk from the gem store, it's more like cooking an advanced recipe. Happy to take this to chat if you want to discuss further, but we can probably leave it there as well.